# How does tf.EagerTensor gets coerced into ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Apparently this code works:

```
# TF 2.2
t = tf.constant([[1., 2., 3.], [4., 5., 6.]])
print(type(t))
print(np.square(t))
```

prints:

```
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>
[[ 1.  4.  9.]
 [16. 25. 36.]]
```

`np.square` expects `ndarray`, but the code works when `t` is of type `tf.EagerTensor`. I thought numpy does not know about TF at all, so how does `tf.EagerTensor` gets coerced into `ndarray`?

Comment: Since it returned a `tf`, it looks more like it delegated the action to tensor's own methods.  Trying `np.square({})` produces: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'dict' and 'dict'", meaning it's tried to multiply the object by itself.  In your case does `t*t` work?

Comment: @hpaulj thanks, `t * t` does work. That explains it.